# Sums of different infinite series equal the same thing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can anyone tell me how $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2^{n-2}(n^2-3n+2)}{n!}\right)$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{n}}{n!}$$ both equal $$\frac{e^2}{2}$$.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question to provide a context for the reason you're asking it.  Also, state things you've attempted here.

Comment: The second one is $e^2$, by the usual Taylor expansion for $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second expression should be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{n!}$.

Hint: rewrite $\quad n^3-3n+2\quad$ as $\quad n(n-1) -2n + 2$.